# how to grep lines after third comma with condition

Tags: awk, sed, grep, regular-expression, text-formatting

I want to view lines from text which is 4 digits after third comma.

> Input:

```
123456789012345,00,0000,000
111111111111111,00,0000,0000
```

> Output:

`111111111111111,00,0000,0000`

Comment: Should it match on `1,2,3,0000xx` or `1,2,3,1111222` or `1,2,3,1111,5` which also have 4 digits after the third comma?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas my question were about only after third comma. if there's 4 digits after it !

Comment: That does really answer the question, is it _4 digits_ and then the end of the line, or _4 digits_ and then anything after (or only non-digits, or comma if anything)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, 'length($4) == 4' file
111111111111111,00,0000,0000
```

Comment: Note that it also matches on `1,2,3,0000,5` and `1,2,3,1-20` but not `1,2,3,0000-5`.

Answer (score 1):

To match namely *4 digits after third comma* :

```
awk -F, '$4~/^[0-9]{4}$/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

To match on lines that have only decimal digits and then the end of the line (that is nothing else, not even a comma allowed after) after the third comma, with `grep`:

```
grep -xE '([^,]*,){3}[0-9]{4}' <file
```